# What do &=, |=, and ~ do in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I frequently see code like this at work:

```
overlap &= group['ADMSN_DT'].loc[i] <= group['epi_end'].loc[j]
```

My question is what do operators such as `&=`, `|=`, and `~` do in pandas?

Comment: in most c-ish based languages, they're short cuts. `foo X= ...` is simply `foo = foo X...`

Comment: Since "[Series are ndarray-like](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series-is-ndarray-like)", you should probably wonder [what in-place operators do in numpy](/questions/16034672/how-do-numpys-in-place-operations-e-g-work).

Comment: Those are element-wise logical operators that work on Series/DataFrames. With assignment (`ser1 &= ser2`) they work as usual, as Marc B said: `ser1 = ser1 & ser2`.

Comment: so |= is for intersection and &= is for a union?

Comment: @Rhymoid I understand what inplace operators do. However, I'm not sure these are inplace operators or rather they are bitwise operators (maybe).

Comment: It's the other way around. `x |= y` is for inplace union (like "or"), `x &= y` is for inplace intersection (like "and").

Comment: @rhymoid sorry for all the annoying questions but would these type of operators only work for numpy arrays and pandas series or dataframes too?

Comment: They have nothing to do with unions or intersections. `pd.Series([True, False, True]) & pd.Series([False, True, True])` returns `pd.Series([False, False, True])` so the operator is applied element-wise.

Comment: They also work on DataFrames. The result is a DataFrame with an index that consists of supersets of the indices of the operands. The values are element-wise (like ayhan correctly points out) results of `&` and `|`.

Comment: @ayhan You're right that they're not really unions and intersections per se. They do resemble those operations when boolean series are used as an array subscript, though.

Comment: The comments and reply answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

> The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. These must be
>   grouped by using parentheses.

[Augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements)

> An augmented assignment evaluates the target (which, unlike normal
>   assignment statements, cannot be an unpacking) and the expression
>   list, performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment
>   on the two operands, and assigns the result to the original target.
>   The target is only evaluated once.

just like `a += 1` increments `a`, `a &= b` compares `a` and `b` and assigns the result to `a`.

```
a = 1
b = 0
print(a & b)
>>> 0
a &= b
print(a)
>>> 0
```

And a `pandas` example

Let's generate a dataframe of zeros and ones.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(6,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(6,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Our initial dataframe

```
print(a)
```

> ```
>    A  B  C  D
> 0  0  1  1  0
> 1  0  0  1  0
> 2  1  0  0  1
> 3  1  1  0  0
> 4  0  0  0  1
> 5  0  0  0  0
> ```

```
print(b)
```

> ```
>    A  B  C  D
> 0  0  0  0  0
> 1  1  1  1  0
> 2  0  1  1  1
> 3  0  1  1  1
> 4  1  1  1  0
> 5  1  1  1  1
> ```

The 4th row of `a` and `b`

```
print(a.loc[3])
```

> ```
> A    1
> B    1
> C    0
> D    0
> Name: 1, dtype: int32
> ```

```
print(b.loc[3])
```

> ```
> A    0
> B    1
> C    1
> D    1
> Name: 1, dtype: int32
> ```

Now evaluate and assign row 4

```
a.loc[3] &= b.loc[3]
```

Row 4 of `a` has changed. Only where both rows have 1 at the same position a 1 is written back to `a`.

```
print(a.loc[3])
```

> ```
> A    0
> B    1
> C    0
> D    0
> Name: 3, dtype: int32
> ```

Comment: for & and | what does it mean if there is an = sign following it as shown in the example?

Comment: @bigdata It does the operation and then assigns the result to the name on the left

Comment: So for the following code import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
a &= b

Comment: so for the following code
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
a &= b
 returns an error of 
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @bigdata You would need comparable data types, see the updated example.